# ImageView shows Drawable translucent/transparent on some devices

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, png

We have a TextView containing a drawable-left and drawable-right from app resources. On some devices like

- Sony Xperia L running Android 4.1.2,
- Samsung Galaxy Young or
- Samsung Galaxy SII

we are facing a strange problem. The drawable will be shown translucent/transparent. On other devices like

- Samsung Galaxy S4 (4.4.2) or
- HTC ONE V (4.0.3)

the drawable will be shown correctly.

This is a cutout of the Layout definition:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button_current_warnings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_classic_list_item"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_classic_current_warning_white"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_classic_row_arrow"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="@string/current_warnings"
            android:textSize="?attr/warningGermanyBoxTextSize"
            android:textColor="?attr/itemFavoriteTitleTextColor"/>
```

On the HTC One V device this layout looks pretty nice:

[image]

On the Sony Xperia L the layout is broken, due to the transparency of the imageview drawables. Both drawables are only shown a little bit:

[image]

Furthermore, if we change the drawable to a different one the result is nice on both devices:

HTC:

[image]

Sony:

[image]

Additionally I attached the two drawables used for my current tests (**they are both white-colored, because of this you will not see anything here**):

Wrong displayed drawable:

[image]

Correct displayed drawable:

[image]

Does anyone face the same problem or has any hints for us?

**Update: In my code, I only set an ClickListener on this TextView:**

```
     buttonGermany = returnView.findViewById(R.id.button_current_warnings);
     buttonGermany.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     buttonGermany.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Do something
        }
     });
```

Comment: Have you anywhere in your app changed the alpha of `@drawable/ic_classic_current_warning_white` drawable (drawable, not view) from code?

Comment: The alpha is not manipulated in code directly. But this drawable is also part of an selector, which uses this drawable based on a state.

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_classic_current_warning_white"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_classic_current_warning_white"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_classic_current_warning_black"/>
</selector>

Comment: This can be caused by some small detail in your app... I think that I won't be able to help you with this without more xml, code etc. But I can give you some other tips: Are there any reasons why hierarchy of this element is so complex? You could reduce the whole `FrameLayout` (with 3 children) into single `TextView` (so it will be 3 views less). Both icons should be placed as `android:drawableLeft` and `android:drawableRight` + have this blue `android:background`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the TextView. It's a nice improvement, but it does not resolve my problem. I will update my question with some more code.

Comment: Current investigation. Problem only arises on Jelly Bean 4.1.2 devices, I assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only encountered this problem on Android 4.1.2 (Jelly Bean) devices. The problem with the translucent presentation of the icons has something to do with caching of drawables in 4.1.2. In my case, I used the wrong ic_classic_current_warning_white-drawable in a drawable-selector, too:

```
<selector xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"> 
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_classic_current_warning_white"/> 
     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_classic_current_warning_white"/> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_classic_current_warning_black"/> 
</selector>
```

This selector was used on a button in previous activity. If I touched this button, the above view appears. By using the `android:exitFadeDuration` the ic_classic_current_warning_white-drawable was faded out after touching my button. But it seems to be that the drawable cache holds a reference to ic_classic_current_warning_white-drawable with an alpha-value lower than 100%, when the new activity was opened. If I used this drawable again in next view, it was not displayed with 100% alpha, but with the alpha-value when leaving the previous activity.

My current solution is simply to duplicate the drawable ic_classic_current_warning_white. One will be used for the selector. The other copy will be used for "static" purposes.